# add www on http and remove www on https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do the following:

add www to non secure
http://domain[.]com to http://www.domain[.]com

&

remomve www on secure
https://www[.]domain.com to https://domain[.]com

I am trying this but doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your second **HTTP_HOST** condition still checks that the `www.` is missing, which should be the other way around.